# Vue + Vuetify submitting form with GET method passes empty values

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem with my code. I can't find a reason why my GET parameters are empty when the form is submitted.

What I'm trying to achieve is to submit the form after validation and be redirected to http://someurl.com/?service=3&propert_type=2. Is it even possible? Or do I need to stringify it and then use window.location?

I'm a newbie at Vue, but can't find the internet for a solution so I guess it's something to do with my code.

```
<template>
    <ValidationObserver v-slot="{ valid }" ref="getanoffer">
        <v-form
            class="form form--getanoffer"
            ref="form"
        >
            <ValidationProvider
                rules="required"
                v-slot="{ errors }"
                name="service"
            >
                <v-select
                    v-model="service"
                    name="service"
                    :items="services"
                    placeholder="Select Service"
                    :error-messages="errors"
                    solo
                ></v-select>
            </ValidationProvider>

            <ValidationProvider
                rules="required"
                v-slot="{ errors }"
                name="property_type"
            >
                <v-select
                    v-model="property_type"
                    :items="property_types"
                    name="property_types"
                    item-text="name"
                    item-value="id"
                    placeholder="Select Property Type"
                    :error-messages="errors"
                    solo
                ></v-select>
            </ValidationProvider>

            <v-btn
                color="primary"
                width="100%"
                @click="validate"
                class="v-btn--submit v-btn--no-gutter"
                :loading="loading"
                :disabled=" ! valid"
            >
                Continue
            </v-btn>
        </v-form>
    </ValidationObserver>
</template>

<script>
  import {ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver} from "vee-validate";

  export default {
    components: {
      ValidationProvider,
      ValidationObserver,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        service: null,
        property_type: null,
        form: {

        },
        loading: false,
      }
    },
    props: {
      services: {
        type: Array,
      },
      property_types: {
        type: Array,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      async validate() {
        let form = await this.$refs.getanoffer.validate();

        if (form) {
          this.loading = true;
          this.submit();
          this.$refs.form.$el.submit();
        }
      },

      submit() {

      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets simplify your code

Instead of calling `validate()` on button click, you can add `type="submit"` to your button and in your form you can add `@submit:prevent="validate"`. This doesn't solve the problem but allows you to submit with Enter and every submit button will trigger the validation.

Now for the solution

1- To navigate to external scope you can use windows.open(). Vuetify lets you navigate to an url but you had to put href on your button and control it manually

```js
windows.open('http://someurl.com/')
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/joel_pro2/pen/wvBvqqg?editors=1011)

[Vuetify vee-validate docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms#vee-validate)

Javacript standards say that you should use camelCase for js variables (this.propertyType)

[JS standard](https://standardjs.com/rules.html)

[ESlint Rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase)